# Java inflector to convert plurals to singular forms

Tags: java, inflector

I am using the [Java Inflector library](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/net/java/dev/inflector/inflector/0.7.0/) to convert singular forms to plurals, example : 2 boat => 2 boats. 
However, it fails when the inputs are already plural. 
1 boats => boats,
butterflies => butterflieses

Is there any other Java utility that -
1. Converts plurals to singular when necessary, example : 1 boat => boat
2. Retains plural as it is, if the plural form is required.

Thanks!

Comment: what does inflector return if you pass in some non-nouns such as "in", "and", "enjoy"?

Answer (score 0):

You know, you can make a simulation, first avoid to convert verbs that are already in plural, how? take the verb and convert it to singular, then convert it in plural and check if the result string is the same than the string that is in the input, if not, thats ok, know you know that is not in plural.

Comment: This may fail if u pass in a word like "in", "and", since i guess inflector will also return the same word..correct me if i am wrong.